# how to start QTimer so that the GUI does not hangs-RestartStoppedProcess()-code

Tags: qt, qtimer

I have made new QTimer object in my class's ctor. When the application starts the timer also starts with the specified time. This timer keeps a track of all the process IDs and if finds that a particular process-id is not active(killed from task manager) then it restarts that particular process. Now the issue is my application lags a-bit due to this QTimer object and only after the timeout, the application becomes smooth. But after 5 seconds the timer starts again and the application starts lagging again. What is the best alternative to start a QTimer object apart from ctor of a class?

```
qTimer = new QTimer(0);

connect(qTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(RestartStoppedProcess()), Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(qTimer, SIGNAL(destroyed()), qTimer, SLOT(deleteLater()), Qt::DirectConnection);

qTimer->setTimerType(Qt::VeryCoarseTimer);
qTimer->start(5000);


void ProcessMonitor::RestartStoppedProcess()
{
    try
    {
        QProcess *objMonitorProcess = new QProcess(this);
        connect(objMonitorProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), objMonitorProcess, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        for(int i = 0; i < ui->twShowProcess->rowCount(); i++)
        {
#ifdef Q_WS_LIN
            //            objMonitorProcess->start("pidof", QStringList() << (ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 0)->text()), QIODevice::ReadOnly);
            objMonitorProcess->start("pidof "+ (ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 0)->text()), QIODevice::ReadOnly);
#elif Q_WS_WIN
            QString cmd("wmic process where ");
            QString qszFilters("\"processid=\'");
            QString qszSubFilters = qszFilters.append(ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 1)->text().append("\'").append("\"").append(" get name"));
            cmd.append(qszSubFilters);
            objMonitorProcess->start(cmd.toStdString().c_str(), QIODevice::ReadOnly);
#else
            QString qszProcessName = ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 0)->text().split(".").takeFirst();
            objMonitorProcess->start("pgrep", QStringList() << qszProcessName, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
#endif
            if((objMonitorProcess->waitForStarted(4000) == true) && (objMonitorProcess->state() == QProcess::Running))
            {
                if(objMonitorProcess->waitForFinished(3000) == false)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    QString qszProcessStatus = ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 3)->text();
                    if(qszProcessStatus.compare("Running") == 0)
                    {
                        QString qszStandardOutput, qszStandardError;
                        qszStandardOutput.clear(); qszStandardError.clear();
                        qszStandardOutput = QString(objMonitorProcess->readAllStandardOutput());
                        qszStandardError = QString(objMonitorProcess->readAllStandardError());
                        if(qszStandardError.simplified().compare("No Instance(s) Available.", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0 && qszStandardOutput.simplified().isEmpty() == true)
                        {
                            ui->twShowProcess->selectRow(i);
                            if(ui->twShowProcess->selectedItems().at(0)->text().compare("LTtagdb.exe", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0 ||
                                    ui->twShowProcess->selectedItems().at(0)->text().compare("LTmessagebroker.exe", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0)
                                this->StopAllApplicationsForcefully();
                            else
                                this->on_actionStop_triggered();

                            if(this->ptrobjContextMenu->isVisible())
                                this->ptrobjContextMenu->close();

                            ui->twShowProcess->clearSelection();

                            if(mobj_ProcessLogMap.mobj_ProcessAndLogMapping.contains(ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 8)->text()) == true)
                            {
                                mobj_ProcessLogMap.mobj_ProcessAndLogMapping.remove(ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 8)->text());
                                mobj_ProcessLogMap.mobj_ProcessAndLogMapping.insert(ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 8)->text(), QString(""));
                            }
                            else
                                this->mobj_ProcessLogMap.mobj_ProcessAndLogMapping.insert(ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 8)->text(), QString(""));
                        }

                        if(ui->twShowProcess->item(i, 0)->text() == "LThistdb.exe")
                        {
                            if(IsServiceRunning(QString("LThistdb.exe")) == false)
                                this->on_actionStopPostgreSQL_DB_Server_triggered();
                        }
                        qszStandardOutput.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                break;
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
            cmd.clear();
            qszFilters.clear();
            qszSubFilters.clear();
#endif
        }
    }
    catch(QProcess::ProcessError pError)
    {
        QMessageBox objCrashExit;
        objCrashExit.information(this, "Crashed", "Process error returned code: " + QString::number(pError));
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        QMessageBox objCrashExit;
        objCrashExit.information(this, "Unknown Crash", "Unknown crash exit-child process may not be running correctly!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Qt::DirectConnection` argument is unnecessary. The automatic connection does exactly what you need. Code less create more mantra FTW. Also there's no need to give an explicit null parent to the timer constructor, simply have `timer = new QTimer;` or better yet hold `QTimer` by value as a member in your class. Finally, connecting the `destroyed` signal to `deleteLater` slot is nonsense. The object is already being destructed, you don't need to delete it later!

Comment: This is a very poor question because you show no code actually causing the problem. Your issue has nothing to do with timers, everything to do with what the `RestartStoppedProcess` slot is doing. Until you show the code for `RestartStoppedProcess`, this question will remain deficient and is subject to being closed for insufficient information. Strive to provide **complete** code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`QTimer` runs in the UI thread so it blocks your UI if it takes a long time to execute. A simple solution is to just run your "processing" stuff in another background thread, the easiest way to do that in Qt might be using [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#run) like this from your timeout slot called from the `QTimer`:

```
QtConcurrent::run(yourProcessingFunction);
```

You can obviously create your own Thread and use the build in `QTimer` from [QObject::startTimer(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer), but that is more work usually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to the amount of work being done by `RestartStoppedProcess`.

As the [documentation for QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details) states, when discussing the called slot:

> It should be written in such a way that it always returns quickly (typically after processing one data item) so that Qt can deliver events to the user interface and stop the timer as soon as it has done all its work.

As you've witnessed with your application, a heavy workload with a `QTimer` on the main thread can cause lag in the Gui. The Qt documentation goes on to state:

> This is the traditional way of implementing heavy work in GUI applications, but as multithreading is nowadays becoming available on more and more platforms, we expect that zero-millisecond QTimer objects will gradually be replaced by QThreads.

With this in mind, I suggest refactoring your code so that `RestartStoppedProcess` functions in a separate thread. There's a great tutorial on ["How to Really Truly Use QThread" here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).